# How to intergrate solana programs with Python

Tags: python, solana, solana-py

There is a solana program I would like to interact with. There is also a web interface that interacts with this solana program. I can't get any results because the javascript code is obfuscated.
All I have now is some hex ABI data and the program address.
At the same time I can decode the tx data sent to the RPC by monitoring the network activity.

I want to interact with this program in Python. I don't have access to the code of the Solana program, I don't have access to the parameters. Is it possible to do this? If possible, how?

Comment: This might help: https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/